# Raycast not hitting at correct mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Think this is a very simple issue but need some fresh eyes - the event from my SelectionManager(showing UI element) only works when the mouse is in slightly the wrong position.

[image: Rock5(Blue) is item I want to prompt UI but instead it shows on Rock6]
[image: Game play showing where mouse has to be for UI element to be active. Blue is what I want.]

I'm a rooky and my attempts at fixes haven't worked

- Tried adjusting mouse sensitivity
- I've also attempted to change colliders from Mesh to Box with no hope.
- Changing RayCast distance didn't make any difference

The code I've got so far in my SelectionManager is:

```
 public GameObject interaction_Info_UI;
    public GameObject interaction_item_origin;
    public GameObject interaction_item_classification;
    public GameObject interaction_item_description;
    public GameObject interaction_item_closerlook;
    public GameObject interaction_item_minerals;
    public float distanceToHit = 5000;
    Text interaction_text_name;
    Text interaction_text_origin;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        interaction_text_name = interaction_Info_UI.GetComponent<Text>();
        interaction_text_origin = interaction_item_origin.GetComponent<Text>();
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            var selectionTransform = hit.transform;
 
            if (selectionTransform.GetComponent<InteractableObject>())
            {
                interaction_text_name.text = selectionTransform.GetComponent<InteractableObject>().GetItemName();
                interaction_Info_UI.SetActive(true);
                interaction_text_origin.text = selectionTransform.GetComponent<InteractableObject>().GetItemOrigin();
                interaction_item_origin.SetActive(true);
            }
            else 
            { 
                interaction_Info_UI.SetActive(false);
                interaction_item_origin.SetActive(false);
            }
 
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: is your mouse cursor locked?

Comment: Have you tried using `Convex` colliders? In your case it's way cheaper to process and there doesn't seem to be the need for allowing concave collider .. + maybe some wrong normal might break it ... Also in general you probably also want to disable your info text in the case you don't hit anything at all with your ray ;)

Comment: Thank you both for replying! My mouse is locked yes @BugFinder, although I think it does have something to do with mousePosition - here's my script ` void Update()
    {
       float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
       float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
       xRotation -= mouseY;
       xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
       YRotation += mouseX;
       transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, YRotation, 0f);
 
    }` :))

Comment: @derHugo I appreciate the Convex Collider tip, however, it shows the mesh is in the collider is in the right position but problem still stands. I added a basic normal map (just to make sure) and doesn't seem to have made a difference either. I've already disabled text when inactive :))

Comment: try doing the raycast from screen.width/2, screen.height/2,0

Answer (score -1):

Turn on Mesh Collier's Convex to check if collider position and shape are incorrect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I've tried that and it seems to be in the right place ![image](file:///C:/Users/anna-/OneDrive/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot%202023-11-28%20140139.png "Screenshot") (it's my first time using mini-Markdown so please excuse my formatting if it's wrong)

Comment: that as it shows points to a file on the local c drive which we are unlikely to have you would need to upload it somewhere and provide a link to that.

Comment: I did think that haha! Thanks for the tip, here's a new [link](https://ornate-lolly-59bbbe.netlify.app/)